# Woocommerce cutting only number 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roots-sage

I'm currently using the latest wordpress version with the latest woocommerce version. I have setup my wordpress and woocommerce and everything is working fine except for one thing.

The number '7' doesn't show in the price tag on the product overview page ( image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2jPU.jpg ) and it doesn't show on the product single page in the title -> ( image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2jPU.jpg ) but it does show in the inspector.

I don't have any custom JS/PHP that overwrites or replaces a 7. Every other number is working except for the 7. I can't find anything about this when I google for it.

Is there any fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that isn't a Woocommerce issue, maybe that font has some trouble with character 7?

Can you try to type '7' in the Chrome inspector in the "gerelaerdee" title wich uses the same font? If not the problem is with that font.

You can use another font (the one you use for the telephone number at top left seems to work), or try to find a fixed/updated version.

Comment: @Ferdi I see you are new here, welcome! You should set an answer as correct if it resolved your problem, and / or upvote it, so other readers can find it quickly. You will also earn 2 points ;)

Comment: Yes did that but since I'm new I need some credit to give up and/or down votes. Idk how my message is above the answer but will do it correctly next time, thanks!

Comment: You can set an answer as correct even without reputation. It's different to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was the font. Only thing I don't get it doesnt pick up my font 'cocon-ff-pro' for woocommerce pricing and titles but the rest of the website does pickup the font cocon-ff-pro with the letter 7. Dno.. but thanks for helping!